# How do I create a new subscription in a service bus topic with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to create a new subscription from my backend nodejs solution

I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/create-subscription

But I can not complete it I do not understand how this REST API works and I think Im missing the authorization.

In postman this:

PUT [https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription](https://management.core.windows.net/%7Bsubscription) ID}/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/Topics/Subscriptions/{Subscription Name}

Returns:

`ForbiddenError`
The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

Comment: what are the headers that you are sending along with the request?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma 

Content-Type:application/xml
Namespace:https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{topic}
x-ms-version:2012-03-01

Comment: you can use the package `@azure/arm-servicebus` to create it : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-servicebus

Comment: @FaisalTaibi Do you have any update?

Comment: Took me quite some time to find the [documentation on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/service-bus-readme?view=azure-node-latest#manage-resources-of-a-service-bus-namespace)

Answer (score 1):

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` offers `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` that lets you manage the service-bus resources.

For the problem in this question, you can leverage the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient.createSubscription` method to create a subscription for a topic. A similar method would be present in the `@azure/arm-service-bus` library too.

Here is an example on using `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` - [administrationClient.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/typescript/src/advanced/administrationClient.ts)

Refer to the links below for more info on version 7.0.0 `@azure/service-bus`.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use @azure/service-bus:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus

NodeJS

```
const { ServiceBusAdministrationClient } = require('@azure/service-bus');
            
// Define connection string and related Service Bus entity names here
const connectionString =
          'Endpoint=sb://<REST OF CONNECTION STRING>';
const topicName = 'yourTopic',
const subscriptionName = 'yourNewSubscription'
        
const serviceBusAdministrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);

serviceBusAdministrationClient.createSubscription('yourTopic', 'yourNewSubscription').catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

If you want create filters. Ex with correlation filter:

```
serviceBusAdministrationClient.createRule(
    'yourTopic',
    'yourNewSubscription',
    'CorrelationFilter', //this is the name of the filter
    { correlationId: 'aCorrelationId' }
  );
```